# Custom linearlayout, on constructor get all childviews

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Im having a problem with a custom LinearyLayout, its basically a class that inherits from the LinearLayout.. nothing fancy.. 
The thing is that I need to fetch all the child-views thats inside my custom linearlayout.. 
I have tried:

```
this.getChildCount();
```

But it keeps returning zero, and Im starting to think that maybe the children hasent been added yet during the time I run this code in the constructor?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. May be you are right. But if you could post the code we can be more clear with the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks alot!
Ended up doing this:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate ()
{
    super.onFinishInflate();
    childs = this.getChildCount();
}
```

Since I used the childs variable in the activity, and there for needed to set the value before I hit the activity-onCreate..which this solved :)

Thanks for your guidence!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should move the `this.getChildCount();` related code inside the `onLayout`. Infact `onLayout` is called when  the view should assign a size and position to each of its children

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the child count of the linearlayout after it is been inflated in an activity.